# Which data structure for List of objects + datagrid view

Tags: data-structures, datagridview, language-agnostic

I have to develop a code which will store a list of objects, as example below

101, value 11, value 12, value 13 ...etc

102, value 21, value 22, value 23 ...etc

103, value 31, value 32, value 33 ...etc

104, value 41, value 42, value 43 ...etc

Now, the difficulty is, that first column is an identifier, and whole table should always be sorted by it. Easy access to each element is required. Additionally, list should be easily updated, and extended by adding element at the end as well as in front and still keep being sorted by first column. 
Finally, I would like to be able to display values of the above in datagridview.

What is most important is a performance of the implementation, as rows will be updated many times per second, and datagridview should be able to display all changes immediately.

I was thinking about creating class for the values, and then a Dictionary but encountered a problem with displaying values in gridview. What would be the most optimal way of implementing the code?

Comment: Wouldn't a listview suffice (similar to how windows explorer right side pane shows & refreshes)?

Comment: you have lists of lists?  List<List<object>> myListList

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately listview is not going to be clear enough, it has to be displayed as an array like in the example above
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

just for the future reference: I found DataTable to be excellent in this case. Its quick and can be easily populated into datagridview.